# Gitlab: revert the local copy of a repository to the current version fo the code on the cloud

Tags: repository, cloud, gitlab

I have an issue with my local repository and I did not push this yet. Now, I would like to restore the version that is actually in my cloud. I found some similar question and solution (like [this](https://github.com/francopestilli/life/wiki/Revert--the-local-copy-of-a-repository-to-the-current-version-fo-the-code-on-the-cloud)) but what I want is not just temporarily switch back to my cloud version, I want it to be fully restored in my local repository.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to revert all changes uncommited in local branch

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```